# How to get the absolute path of the imported python file

Tags: python, file, directory

I have following code structure:

```
config_dir
    config.py

main.py
```

There is a method in config.py as follows:

```
def get_path():
    # TODO 
    return "the absolute path of config.py, not the path of the main.py that import this config module"
```

in the main.py, I import the config module and call config's method get_path

```
from config_dir import config

print(config.get_path())
```

I would like print the absolute path of config.py, not the path of the main.py that import this config module

I would like how to code this, thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
import os
os.path.abspath(config)
```

#### edit-1 (credits: Milan Cermak)

Add the following code in `config.py`

```py
import os

def get_path():
    return os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

Comment: thanks @dexter. You mean run this code in main.py? I want to get the path in the config.py, not in the main.py

Comment: Yes, run this in main.py

Answer (score 2):

You can use **file** to get absolute path for imported module. For example:

```
from config_dir import config

print(config.__file__)
```

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.__file__
'/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
import os

def get_path():
    return os.path.abspath(__file__)
```